# Is it possible to use AMAZON LEX to build a chatbot which connects with database and Web service stored on client side?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, chatbot, amazon-lex

Our organization wants to develop a **"LOST & FOUND System Application"** using chatbot integrated in a website.

Whenever the user starts the conversation with the chatbot, the chatbot should ask the details of lost item or item found and it should store the details in database.

How can we do it ?

And can we use our own web-service because organization doesn't want to keep the database in Amazon's Server.

Comment: Everything you said it's possible, from the conversation, saving to an external db. I suggest starting at 'how to build a web service' using the language of your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone who just implemented this very same situation (with a lot of help from @Sid8491), I can give some insight on how I managed it.

Note, I'm using C# because that's what the company I work for uses.

First, the bot requires input from the user to decide what intent is being called. For this, I implemented a PostText call to the Lex API.

```
PostTextRequest lexTextRequest = new PostTextRequest()
        {
            BotName = botName,
            BotAlias = botAlias,
            UserId = sessionId,
            InputText = messageToSend
        };

        try
        {
            lexTextResponse = await awsLexClient.PostTextAsync(lexTextRequest);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new BadRequestException(ex);
        }
```

Please note that this requires you to have created a Cognito Object to authenticate your AmazonLexClient (as shown below):

```
protected void InitLexService()
    {
        //Grab region for Lex Bot services
        Amazon.RegionEndpoint svcRegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1;

        //Get credentials from Cognito
        awsCredentials = new CognitoAWSCredentials(
                            poolId,                     // Identity pool ID
                            svcRegionEndpoint);         // Region

        //Instantiate Lex Client with Region
        awsLexClient = new AmazonLexClient(awsCredentials, svcRegionEndpoint);
    }
```

After we get the response from the bot, we use a simple switch case to correctly identify the method we need to call for our web application to run. The entire process is handled by our web application, and we use Lex only to identify the user's request and slot values.

```
//Call Amazon Lex with Text, capture response
var lexResponse = await awsLexSvc.SendTextMsgToLex(userMessage, sessionID);

//Extract intent and slot values from LexResponse
string intent = lexResponse.IntentName;
var slots = lexResponse.Slots;

//Use LexResponse's Intent to call the appropriate method 
switch (intent)
{
    case: /*Your intent name*/:
    /*Call appropriate method*/;
    break;
}
```

After that, it is just a matter of displaying the result to the user. Do let me know if you need more clarification!

UPDATE:

An example implementation of the slots data to write to SQL (again in C#) would look like this:

```
 case "LostItem":                                              
      message = "Please fill the following form with the details of the item you lost.";
      LostItem();
      break;
```

This would then take you to the LostItem() method which you can use to fill up a form.

```
public void LostItem()
{
    string itemName = string.Empty;
    itemName = //Get from user
    //repeat with whatever else you need for a complete item object

    //Implement a SQL call to a stored procedure that inserts the object into your database. 
    //You can do a similar call to the database to retrieve an object as well
}
```

That should point you in the right direction hopefully. Google is your best friend if you need help with SQL stored procedures. Hopefully this helped!

Comment: I am a complete rookie and also a fresher graduate. So forgive me if I am asking anything silly 
Once the user answers all the questions for the item he found, Lex should be able to store it on our database and should be able to match it with the query if someone reports his lost item.
And also do we need to use Lamda function ?

Comment: that is fantastic and detailed answer, glad I could help.

Comment: @PankajSingh, its ok! I'm a fresher graduate too! I personally don't use lambda in my bot's usage but that's up to you. Since our web application handles everything, we can read/write to our sql database with the data from Lex. Lex doesn't "do" anything other than identify the intent and get the slot values, which then passed into a method that does the actual processing of the data. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: It is important to note that my bot doesn't do the slot filling. I handle everything on my web application so that I can customize every message that is being shown to the user. If you find it easier to use Lex's interface, that is your choice. Displaying all the messages to the user can be difficult to code if you're not good at HTML/Javascript so I can recommend you to go to the lex-web-ui github (https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lex-web-ui) if you want to use the AWS Web UI to show your messages.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible.

You can send the requests to Lex from your website which will extract Intents and Entities.
Once you get these, you can write backend code in any language of your choice and use any DB you want.
In your use case, you might just want to use Lex. [PostText](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostText.html) will be main function you will be calling.

You will need to create an intent in Lex which will have multiple slots `LosingDate`, `LosingPlace` or whatever you want, then it will be able to get all these information from the user and pass it to your web application.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.
The system is something like this.
First the user will open the chatbot and he will either enter "I have lost something" or "I have found something."
then there will be series of questions asked by the chatbot like what was the product. where did you lose it, when did you lose it etc etc.
after that the company wants to store all the details of the item lost/found in the database so that it can be used for match found if any user is searching for his lost item. but all the data should be stored on company's server and not Amazon's server.
can you please help ?

Comment: thats what i wrote, you will be creating NLP part on Lex, you will pass the queries from your web service get result from the lex, do the data processing on company's server. updated the answer as well.

Comment: how will we connect our web service to the LEX ?

Comment: Sir, do we need to use Lambda function anywhere ?

Comment: @PankajSingh that depends on you, its just a backend code. If you like you can have backend code at your own server and handle the Lex request response from there. I would suggest to read up little about Lex.